# Registrar y Listar una Grilla manteniendo su fila de edicion SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tengo un problema, no puedo corregir un STORED PROCEDURE, el cual trabaja con una web en C# donde se encuentra una grilla de 4 filas, INSERTA normal en la fila con el indice que le corresponde pero al grabarlo SUBE esa fila INSERTADA a la primera fila, luego si inserto en la fila 4 se graba con el indice 4 pero al grabarlo se coloca en la segunda fila debajo de la primera.
Aqui dejo el codigo del STORED PROCEDURE:

```
Select top 4 a.*
From (
        select TOP 1 Id_Participacion as IdParticipacion
        ,Id_Tipo as IdTipo
        ,Total_Mensual as Total_Mensual
        ,BP as BP_Participacion
        ,Observaciones as Observaciones
        ,Matricula as Matricula
        ,Fecha_Creacion as Fecha_Creacion from BD_DESAGED.dbo.D268_ParticipacionBCP a
        where a.Codunicocli = '0000106897916' AND a.Codunicocli= '0'
        and a.Id_Tipo = 0 and a.Id_Visita = 320 

        union all

        select TOP 1 Id_Participacion as IdParticipacion
        ,Id_Tipo as IdTipo
        ,Total_Mensual as Total_Mensual
        ,BP as BP_Participacion
        ,Observaciones as Observaciones
        ,Matricula as Matricula
        ,Fecha_Creacion as Fecha_Creacion from BD_DESAGED.dbo.D268_ParticipacionBP a
        where a.Codunicocli = '0000106897916' and a.Id_Tipo = 1 and a.Id_Visita = 320

        union all

        select TOP 1 Id_Participacion as IdParticipacion
        ,Id_Tipo as IdTipo
        ,Total_Mensual as Total_Mensual
        ,BP as BP_Participacion
        ,Observaciones as Observaciones
        ,Matricula as Matricula
        ,Fecha_Creacion as Fecha_Creacion from BD_DESAGED.dbo.D268_ParticipacionBP a
        where a.Codunicocli = '0000106897916' and a.Id_Tipo = 2 and a.Id_Visita = 320

        union all

        select TOP 1 Id_Participacion as IdParticipacion
        ,Id_Tipo as IdTipo
        ,Total_Mensual as Total_Mensual
        ,BP as BP_Participacion[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
        ,Observaciones as Observaciones
        ,Matricula as Matricula
        ,Fecha_Creacion as Fecha_Creacion from BD_DESAGED.dbo.D268_Participacion a
        where a.Codunicocli = '0000106897916' and a.Id_Tipo = 3 and a.Id_Visita = 320
```

Aqui adjunto la grilla en C# que como indico inserte en la fila 3 pero al grabarlo se coloca en la primera fila de igual manera al listar.
¿Habra alguna sentencia que me capture el dato de la fila insertada compatandola en que indice (Id_Tipo) se inserto y que las demas filas inserte ceros para que me muestre donde se inserto? Agredeceria su ayuda.

[image: ![TABLA A LISTAR]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTX59.png)

Comment: Los datos salen en orden de consulta del FROM? Y a la hora de traerte los datos de la base da datos, por qué no le haces un ORDER BY (id o el campo que desees que estén ordenados)? Saludos!!

Comment: Hola Hector, ya lo e intentado pero me ordena como si hubiera solo puesto esa fila a modificar , osea si inserto 1 fila, me ordena y aparece ese fila mientras que en las otas filas deberia contar con valor ceros y aparecer. Mira adjunto las columnas de las tablas para que se te pueda guiar..te agradeceria si me ayudaras con una sentencia para que asigne valor ceros en los que no se inserto.

![Columnas de PARTICIPACION]!( )

Comment: Id_participacion | Id_visita| Codunicocli | Id_tipo | Total_Mensual | Bcp | Observaciones | Matricula | Fecha_creacion    

* No se como se sube una imagen

Comment: Hola, disculpa mi torpeza pero no termino de entender bien lo que te pasa, me explico, tienes esa tabla con 4 registros, entonces insertas un registro, y tú ese registro quieres que aparezca en la fila número 3 no? Ahora bien, no te aparece en la fila 3. (pero por qué campo estás ordenando?) Podrías editar tu respuesta para poner el código referente a esa parte por favor? Saludos!! :)

Comment: Buenas Hector, gracias por el interes, efectivamente quiero que al registrar se mantenga el registro y la lista en la fila que inserto y que siempre se mantenga el formato de 4 filas..osea que si REGISTRO EN LA FILA 2, que la fila 0,1 y 3 se llenen de ceros para que al terminar el registro y listado se mantenga el orden... Y tendria que salir asi:  EN UNA VISITA  que se muestre las 4 filas .


* con respecto al codigo no te entendi, al incio adjunto la parte del codigo que supuestamente registra y lista con el SELECT TOP... pero solo me sale la fila que inserte mas no las 4 filas.. PORFAVOR